# exe generated by pyinstaller is not executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote a python app which uses tkinter, pyzbar, PIL and some other commonly used libraries. The app decodes the QR code in camera image and opens certain images or files. The app works perfectly fine. Now when I am trying to create exe for the app with pyinstaller, I am getting a few problems.

First, importing PIL and running "pyinstaller .py" gives me "Cannot find existing PyQT5 plugin directories", and the exe file is not generated. However, I overcame the problem by editing the "excludes" in the .spec file as `excludes = ['FixTk', 'PySide', 'PyQT4', 'PyQT5']`. I don't know if it's the right thing to do. I just found `excludedimports = [modname_tkinter, 'FixTk', 'PySide', 'PyQT4', 'PyQT5']` in the *hook-PIL.py* file and thought of adding these to the spec file.

Second, I tried to run the exe and got "Failed to execute script *filename*". This happened because I imported "pyzbar". I then tried with the simplest piece of code, but kept the imports as it was. Just to make sure the problem is not causing from the code body. Getting the same problem.

```
import tkinter, pyzbar 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
l = Label(F, text="Hello")
f.pack()
l.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 3.6.5 and pyinstaller 3.4 from anaconda. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the exe—get any error messages? Does pyinstaller produce any messages? Try to create and example wit the smallest amount of code in it that reproduces the problem. For example, if PIL and pyzbar aren't used, don't even `import` them. Once you figured out how to make it work with just tkinter, then perhaps the same sort thing will also work fro other modules.

Comment: @martineau...I get "failed to execute script filename" when I run the exe.

Comment: @martineau...I did try without the additional imports. Works just fine. But my main app requires those imports. That's why I was checking if the problem occurs with the imports only. I found in the this (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) link that pyzbar is not in the supported package list. Does that mean there is no way I can make pyzbar to work with pyinstaller?  Thanks

Comment: That list at the github link shows Pillow as working OK, which reminded me that nowadays that's actually the "PIL" being distributed with Python (it's a fork of PIL). One thing that's different though is you don't use it by importing the whole thing like your code is doing. See this [pillow tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/handbook/tutorial.html) for how to use it. As for `pyzbar`, you may be able to get it working if you can figure out how to deal with the non-Python shared library (aka DLL on Windows) `zbar` it requires.

Comment: @martineau...About `PIL`, I actually made a mistake posting the code in the question. I am not importing the whole thing like I wrote. It's actually `from PIL import ImageTk, Image`. Thanks for pointing that out....About your suggestion on `pyzbar`, I have no idea how to do it. need to look further I guess.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @martineau...Windows 10 Pro

Comment: My only other suggestion at this point would be to attempt to simplify things so you can figure out which one of the things being imported is causing this issue. As I said earlier, I suspect it's got something to do with `pyzbar`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will spend some time again on this on January